# HTML - Post injection from external PHP file

Tags: php, html

Just got a thought, assuming there is a form which has variable storing some data (based on which - form will be processed accordingly).

Say user got a referal/registration link in their email to follow to register, let's say url with encrypted GET variable like: `http://www.example.com?a42as231Adab`

For example there is a form which gets id from that get variable:

```
$usersID = decrypt($_GET['user']);
<form method='POST' action='viewdata.php?userID=$usersID'>
```

since user can click view source code and they will easily see where action is leading and what userID it's parsing.

so what would prevent somebody from:
Creating a blank new PHP file on their server, copying original form into their PHP file and changing it to:

```
<form method='POST' action='viewdata.php?userID=1'>
```

I mean assuming in this scenario userID is sequential, so 1,2,3 may end up administrator.

And lets say viewdata.php if it notices userID is admin, it will allow user to manage something.

In other words: is there any way to prevent form being posted from anything but specific domain?

I know that's probably considered very poor security measures if user can be given access based just on their ID, but still, I am curious about this, it's just a random thought I got.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is about, but I think your are talking about CSRF vulnerabilities?

Comment: So what you're saying is that when a user visits that page with the encrypted user-id he is actually logged in as that user (lets say user 23)?. (edit:) And thus he may only POST to viewdata.php?userID=23

Comment: In simple words: If form action depends on specific variable, what stops user from altering that variable by sending form from external domain where he can script his own php form and make modifications to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want anyone messing around with sensitive information, just don't give it to them. The same way your `index.php` handled this information in encrypted form, `viewdata.php` could do the same.

You could also store it in `$_SESSION` and make `viewdata.php` fetch it from there. Thats the kind of stuff why `$_SESSION` is there for.

To prevent cross-site posting, use a postkey. For example:

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='viewdata.php?userID=$usersID'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='postkey' value='" . session_id() . "'>';
```

Now in `viewdata.php`, check if `$_POST['postkey'] == session_id()` to know if that user really submitted the formulary or if he was induced to do it by some external source.

Comment: So pretty much the only way to hide information from user yet still be able to access it across pages is using session?

Comment: No. You can use cryptography.

Comment: I like to use a combination of checksum + AES block cypher + base64 to generate strings with sensitive data I can safely hand to the user to be processed by other pages. He cant read it because its cryptographed, and he cant mess with it even to generate random behaviour because theres a checksum behind the encryption ensuring the decrypt result is safe to rely on.